# MYSQL multicolumn indexing

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, non-clustered-index

I have a query that uses a foreign key and other column(say c1) in where clause. By default, foreign key is indexed. When i add index to c1 and run explain command, the query takes up only foreign key for searching, not the c1 which is also indexed.

I'm not supposed to create a single index for both foreign key and other column. I tried reading comments related to indexing, any suggestions would be really grateful.

Table:
Student: Id, Name, year, Class_tutor_id

ClassTutor: Id, name

Select name from Student
where Class_tutor_id in 
(Select id from ClassTutor where name='Sally')
and year>=200 and year<=2006;

I have created index in year field. Class_tutor_id is the foreign key referring to ClassTutor table id. When i execute the query with explain command, Under "Keys" column i get the foreign key Class_tutor_id, but in "Possible keys" column, I get foreign key, primary key, year

Comment: Edit your question and show the query and the table definitions (or at least the indexes).  There isn't enough information to really provide confident guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You should create composite index for the two columns:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: I need to use separate index on each column. I created separate index. In the "EXPLAIN" command, i didn't get "index merge" in type column. The newly created index is not taken into consideration. Is there any other means of doing it?

Comment: You can't use two separate indexes for the where clause. If you want to use two columns, you have to create new index which will contain both of them.

Comment: when i create new index which contain both of them, the foreign key only get used. It didn't work. The new index is also not getting used

Comment: Can i use "USE INDEX(index_name)" explicitly in my query?

Comment: @User12121 - yes you can, it give mySql a hint of which index should be used. you can also FORCE INDEX(index_name) which will force mySql to use it

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`, it performs poorly.  Use a `JOIN` instead:

```
Select  s.name
    from  Student AS s
    JOIN  ClassTutor AS ct  ON ct.id = s.Class_tutor_id
    where  ct.name='Sally'
      and  s.year>=200
      and  s.year<=2006;
```

Then one of these indexes will be used, and be 'optimal':

```
Student:  INDEX(year)
ClassTutor:  INDEX(name, id)  -- "composite" and "covering"
```

Do not `USE` or `FORCE` `INDEX`; it may help today, but hurt tomorrow.

A "separate index on each column" means that you have not learned the power of a "composite" index.  See my [*cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

The `FOREIGN KEY` is a red hearing in this discussion; focus on the necessary index(es).